# Replace NAs in one column with the values of another in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="id_1 id_2 
                  123 NA
                  456 NA
                  NA 3
                  NA 1
                  NA 1", header=T)


> dat
  id_1 id_2
1  123   NA
2  456   NA
3   NA    3
4   NA    1
5   NA    1
```

I'd like to be able to "merge" these columns to produce a resulting `id` column in which the NAs of one column are filled with the values of the other column.  In the event that there are values in both columns, I'd like to just paste the unique values in a comma de-limited list.  Like so:

```
> dat
  id
1  123   
2  456   
3   3    
4   1   
5   1
```

I've tried various iterations on joining and row-wise replacement, but I can't figure out the right way to do this in a dplyr chain.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  transmute(id = coalesce(id_1, id_2))
```

Base R solution:

```
dat <- within(dat, {id <- ifelse(is.na(id_1), id_2, id_1); rm(id_1); rm(id_2)})
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `unite` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  unite(id, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

---

If you always have only one non-NA value in each row we can use `coalesce`.

```
dat %>%  mutate(id = coalesce(id_1, id_2))
```